# Are code reviews of kata's welcome here?

Tags: discussion

I occasionally do some 'katas' as programming practise, often in a language I am not particularly familiar with. Are questions asking for feedback on a kata welcome here?

For example, I recently tried the [Yahtzee kata](http://codingdojo.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?KataYahtzee) in Python (first attempt [here](http://pastie.org/2096605)). It would be nice to get a bit of feedback from more experienced Python programmers on whether I have overlooked any useful language features (or indeed any types of improvement that could be made).

Comment: Is `Katas` a plural form of something? What? I can't find the word in my dictionary (except: martial arts).

Comment: @user unknown: It is plural for `Kata` and [it does mean the same as the Martial Arts word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kata_%28programming%29).

Comment: And is it something special, like emphasis on concentration, on teamwork, or something, or does it just mean 'excercise', 'training'? Has it a fix time, which should be sufficient, to solve a Kata? Is it from the Python-world?

Answer (score 9):

Sure, that's perfectly acceptable.